# Intel Linux Graphic Drivers

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics

I want to install the Intel Linux Graphics Drivers through the program, but everytime I've tried to install them this error comes up

```
W:GPG error: https://download.01.org Ubuntu Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8D8847D52F4AAA66
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How do I fix this; I really want to install this so I can play games from Steam.

Processor: Intel® Celeron(R) M CPU 440 @ 1.86GHz
Graphics: Intel® 945GM x86/MMX/SSE2
32-bit Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: Thanks. I encounter the error: gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Run these commands in a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg -O - | \
sudo apt-key add -
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-2 -O - | \
sudo apt-key add -
```

([source](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-linux-graphics-installer-version-1.0.2))

Then retry

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --reinstall install intel-linux-graphics-installer
```

Then run the installer again
([source](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/official-intel-linux-graphics-installer.html))

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful, but W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead. still comes up.

Comment: @bad_charge This is unrelated to Intel Linux Graphics, just try the next commands in my answer. Those errors are for the http://www.openshot.org/ video editor

Comment: Oh, thank you I finally fixed the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You can make ubuntu download the missing key it is complaining about.

In your case: `... the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8D8847D52F4AAA66` copy the hash from error message `8D8847D52F4AAA66`

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8D8847D52F4AAA66
$ sudo apt-get update
```

It should not complain anymore.