# How do I install Intel graphic drivers on Ubuntu 14.04 for DELL Inspiron N4050

Tags: dell, intel, vga

I have DELL Inspiron n4050 i5 4GB RAM laptop and I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on it. I need to install graphic drivers on it and don't know how.

Comment: It should be using the Intel drivers by default. Are you having issues?

Comment: when i installed cairo doc and compiz, animation and effects doesn't work at all. i thought that it is because of Intel drivers. Any idea ??

Comment: @Nattgew then why someone install intel Linux graphic drivers like this post.[link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/339476/intel-linux-graphic-drivers). i really don't have any idea. thanks